# Backward and Forward differences of difference matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the context of difference matrix:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My textbook talks about the backward, centered and forward difference, which confused me. It said the difference matrix produce a backward difference of $2t-1$. What does "difference" here refers to? The textbook(*Introduction to Linear Algebra 5th edition, Gilbert Strang*) derived it using the following method(or analogy):

The vector $x$ changes to a function $x(t)$. The differences Ax becomes the derivative $\frac{dx}{dy}=b(t)$ The differences of squares 0,1,4,9 are odd number 1, 3, 5. The derivative of $x(t)=t^2$ is $2t$. A perfect analogy would produce even number $b = 2,4,6$ at times of $1,2,3$. But differences are not the same a derivatives, and our matrix A produces not $2t$ but $2t-1$:

Backward difference: $$x(t)-x(t-1)=t^2-(t-1)^2 = t^2 - (t^2-2t+1) = 2t-1$$

What does the difference here even mean? I get that the difference matrix is an operation, but how does it outputs a "function"? And **how does the difference matrix find the finite difference**? Thanks!

Comment: Finite differences are differences between $f(x)$ and $f(x-1)$ so they are always $1$ apart unlike the derivative where the differences are arbitrarily small. It outputs a function just like the derivative does.